# Full Screen With toolbar and edittext at the bottom android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toolbar

I am working with Chat application Android.
I am creating Chat screen, exactly like Whats app.

`EditText` at the bottom and `Toolbar` at the top.

I am using following code.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:id="@+id/llFrame">

<include layout="@layout/actionbar_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/White"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewChat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
    android:background="#91f1f1f1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
        >

        <com.cloudzon.gratzeez1.property.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_"
            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.cloudzon.gratzeez1.property.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSendMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And to acquire full screen activity, I am using following code in activity.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Now When I click on `EditText` at the bottom, soft keyboard opens up but pushing the above layout on top and I am not able to see `Toolbar`.

Instead, `Toolbar` should be fixed at his position once user opens edittext.

Thank you

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Comment: Remove FrameLayout as parent and replace it with LinearLayout vertical orientation.

Comment: I tried Linear layout also.

Comment: @Divyesh
I cant use sateHidden, else It wont let me to open keyboard

Comment: thats not it. you can still use keyboard. try it first

Comment: It still not working..@divyesh

Comment: @Divyesh In that case, edittext which is bottom, that can not be visible.

Comment: i used same functionality in my app and it is working perfectly. But i am using Linearlayout and making views programatically

Comment: @JayVyas Where you add toolbar ? In chat Fragment or RootView? If you are include toobar in this chat activity or fragment. Then that is not correct.

Comment: If you are doing that. When keyboard appears, toolbar will also hide.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below example of chat layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearSmsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_msg_icon_sender"
                android:text="This is long text for testing only. This is long text for testing only. This is long text for testing only. This is long text for testing only. This is long text for testing only." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtReceiveMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_msg_icon_receiver"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_400" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtTxtSmsText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/grey_400"
            android:hint="Write a message..."
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnSendSms"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_red" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And also use **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`** in android Manifeast file.

Without Keyboard.

[image]

With Keyboard.

[image]

Comment: I cant use Scroll view, because I am using Recyclerview here to load all chat messages.

Comment: but how can I use recyclerview inside scrollview ?

Comment: Then make it nested scroll view @JayVyas

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in manifest when you declare you activity where this fragment is added.

Use this layout
check this layout it works as expected
Just modify it as per you needs

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/calendar_background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edit_query"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_query"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/color_orange_event_text" />
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" try this.

Comment: If I try this, then It is not pushing the layout up.
But even edit text also.
Keyboard comes over Edit text and makes it invisible

Comment: why are you using framelayout as your parent? Just replace it with LinearLayout once and then check.

Comment: I tried with linear layout also
But I wont get success

Comment: can you just post screen shot of what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

please check this library on GitHub:
https://github.com/DeromirNeves/whatsapp-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:id="@+id/llFrame">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/White"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewChat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#91f1f1f1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSendMessage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Send"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Still not working,
Here I am using this line of code for removing status bar,
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
maybe this is the problem

Comment: If I remove this lines,
Then I am not able to get full screen
I dont want statusbar here